# ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name issue starts at &&start_year and &&end_year

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

```
define start_year = 2017;
define end_year = 2020;

with af as (
    select 
        dd.retail_year as year
        , dd.retail_quarter_of_year as quarter
        , dd.retail_month_of_year as month
        , dd.retail_week_of_year as week
        , 'BN Asset' as asset_type
        , count(bn_sku) as units
        , sum(bn_actual_cost) as cost
    from o_diamond.diamond_asset_file af 
        left join o_warehouse.date_dim dd on af.receipt_date = dd.full_date
    where 1=1
        and dd.retail_year between &&start_year and &&end_year
```

Comment: That query is incomplete - it's missing the closing parenthesis for the CTE and the actual query against the CTE (at least). There isn't a bind variable shown, so it could be in the code you omitted. Please edit the question to show the whole query and the whole error message, including the line number/column position it reports.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is compatible with an undefined substitution variable prefix. Thus you should execute

```
set define &
```

as the first command in your script / interactively. The prefix may be set to a different character in the glogin.sql of the sqlplus client. Use of substitution variables may have been switched off altogether.

[This resource](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables#4_1_2) may be of use (though a bit dated, it should get you started).